# Parent Key and ChildKey are identical in Stimulsoft

Tags: c#, winforms, stimulsoft

I have a problem about parent key and child key are identical when the report show it shows me this error!

I created a view on SQL Server 2008 and I'm getting data from it for a report.

This is my search code in a class:

```
string query = "Select * from vBarname1  where  username = @admin and  shozviat = @shozviat and id = @id";

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@admin", admin));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@shozviat", shozviat));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

return dt;
```

and this is my code for showing report:

```
StiReport report2 = new StiReport();
report2.Load("barname1.mrt");

report2.RegData("barname1", dgbarname1.DataSource);
report2.Show();
//dgbarame1 is a datagirdview
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Is dgbarname1.DataSource == null?

Comment: forget dgbarname1 it was a mistake and i deleted that, which it was a datagridview

Comment: my problem is when i want to take a report it said that " Parent Key and ChildKey are identical"

Comment: and ofcourse ts not null

Comment: Please run the query in Management Studio, and show us the results in your question so we can show you the record where the parent and child ID may be the same.

Comment: https://ufile.io/vk1t0lsu

Comment: https://ufile.io/jc3w54d2

Comment: is anyone here to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to say I solved this problem.
the problem wasn't in my cod I updated my Database I had deleted all the relation in that and it didn't get update in stimulsoft. that's why I get this error "Parent Key and ChildKey are identical"